# Expandable div like functionality

Tags: android, android-layout

I was looking something similar to this http://roshanbh.com.np/examples/exapandable-panel/ for my android application, ie I want to achieve this expandable div like functionality where if somebody click on a name in my application a sub options can pop out. Similar to the expandable div in the above link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) may or may not look like what you are looking for.

Comment: hi thanks can u point me to any example which has some code for the same??